# Set the max length of the row of a particular column only the first time

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I know how to set the maximum length of the row in a particular column of the datagridview but it changes everytime if enter the string of shorter length.I want to set the length such that the max length is set only once at first which is basically the length of the string.

For example if the length of the string is 5 at the start so even if i change the string text and the length is changed to 3 the maximum length remains 5.

This is my code.

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        //check if currently selected cell is cell you want
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != 2)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.Control is TextBox && !(Convert.ToBoolean(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString())))
        {
            ((TextBox)e.Control).MaxLength = Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: create a boolean variable as var isFirstTime =true; then within your code check if(isFirstTime) and set your max length and change this parameter to false.

Answer (score 1):

create a boolean variable as

```
    var isFirstTime =true;
```

then within your code check if(isFirstTime) and set your max length and change this parameter to false.

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    //check if currently selected cell is cell you want
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (e.Control is TextBox && !(Convert.ToBoolean(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString())))
    {
         if(isFirstTime)
         { 
        ((TextBox)e.Control).MaxLength = Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
          isFirstTime=false;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are always different ways to do a same task, but this solution is better than the one i submitted as it is clearer and more importantly it will reduce the number of operation (1 if instead of 2) nice job

Answer (score 0):

What happens in you code is that you define the maxlength dependament on the length of the string. In that case, you need to add to if statement to your code. The first if is going to encompassethe second if of your code and here is its condition

```
if ((TextBox)e.Control).MaxLength >= Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString())
```

This code will prevent you from increasing the size of your maxlength.
The second if will be nested in your second if here is its code.

```
  if ((TextBox)e.Control).MaxLength < Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString())
```

if this is true you do nothing else you apply the the max length definition you have

```
  ((TextBox)e.Control).MaxLength = Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
```

this will prevent a shortening of the maxlength

Comment: The problem is that i have already set the maximum number of length to 130 of all the strings but there are some strings whose maximum length is the same as their string length in the begining.:(

Comment: I'm sorry i'm confused. so you want the maximum length of your cell to be 130, but some cells have to have a maximum that is less than that??
Anyways, look at Elhsan's answer, it is better than mine and it can allow you to define a maximum before you start (130) and then adapt your max to the length of the first string you enter